# Unlinking files in PHP array (PHPMailer)

Tags: php, arrays, phpmailer, unlink

Just a simple question -hello btw, it keeps deleting me my greeting.

This is how I go through an array and upload files

```
$numFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['priloha']['name']));

for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; ++$i) {
  $target_path = './' . basename($_FILES['priloha']['name'][$i]);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['priloha']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) 
  {
  echo "Soubor ".basename($_FILES['priloha']['name'][$i])." byl úspěšně nahrán.<br />";
  }
$mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
}
```

Now after sending, I need to go through the array again and delete all the files like I did with a single file (not an array)

```
if  ($mail->AddAttachment($target_path); !="")
  {
  unlink("$target_path");
  }
```

How is the code gonna look like? I'm not really sure, I still don't know what can I delete from the first "for" cycle. Thanks for your help

Solved, thanks Ivo Pereira :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You only delete the file if is it has been successfully sent.

```
$numFiles = count(array_filter($_FILES['priloha']['name']));

for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; ++$i) {
      $target_path = './' . basename($_FILES['priloha']['name'][$i]);
      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['priloha']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) 
      {
      echo "Soubor ".basename($_FILES['priloha']['name'][$i])." byl úspěšně nahrán.<br />";

      }


    if  ($mail->AddAttachment($target_path) )
    {
      unlink("$target_path");
    }

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you :) I'd give you a plus point if I could, sorry that I'm not allowed to :/

Comment: Sure, I just didn't know that there is something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

is this semicolon allowed?

```
if  ($mail->AddAttachment($target_path)__;__ !="")
```

Comment: Haven't tried yet, I've already got working solution (see above), but are you sure that this would work? I think I have to go through the array file by file...