# PHPMailer - How do I unlink files in temp dir.?

Tags: phpmailer, email-attachments

I am looping through the files array as shown in the middle chunk of code, rest of the code is just for better context.

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'John@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'John Doe';
$email->Subject   = $name_talent;                        
$body = '<strong>ADDRESS</strong> : ' .$address_talent.'<br><br>';

if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $tmp_path = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name = basename($_FILES[$file]['name']);
    $email->AddAttachment($tmp_path, $tmp_name);
    }
}

$email->Body = $body;
$email->IsHTML(true); 
$email->AddAddress( '#####@gmail.com' );
$email->Send();
```

This sends the attachments with values in the $body as well. Now, I would like to unlink the files either after the mail is sent or the attachments are successful. As inspired [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835643/unlinking-files-in-php-array-phpmailer#answer-16835865), If I do it like this below, *no files are attached* and any variables set for the $body eg. `$address_talent` *do not appear* in the email.

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $tmp_path = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
    $tmp_name = basename($_FILES[$file]['name']);
         if($email->AddAttachment($tmp_path, $tmp_name)){
         unlink("$tmp_path");
         }
    }
}
```